# Installing scala from coursier: where is the `scala` command?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I installed scala from https://www.scala-lang.org/download/scala3.html using the coursier option:

```sh
cs install scala3-compiler
cs install scala3-repl
```

After these two steps, I have two binaries in my `$PATH`: `scala3-compiler` and `scala3-repl`.

I am learning scala from the [Programming in Scala](https://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_5ed) book, and in Chapter 4, it said I should compile and run a scala application with the following commands:

```sh
scalac ChecksumAccumulator.scala Summer.scala
scala Summer of love
```

I replaced `scalac` with `scala3-compiler` in the first command, and it produced an `org` directory of the following structure:

```
org/
└── stairwaybook
    └── classesandobjects
        ├── ChecksumAccumulator$.class
        ├── ChecksumAccumulator.class
        ├── ChecksumAccumulator.tasty
        ├── Summer$.class
        ├── Summer.class
        └── Summer.tasty
```

But I cannot find any `scala` command installed in my system, and do not know how to run the compiled bytecodes. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: `scala` starts the REPL for scala 2. For scala 3 REPL you have `scala3-repl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install:

```
cs install scala3
```

Then you should write:

```
scala3-compiler ChecksumAccumulator.scala Summer.scala
scala3 Summer of love
```

It should work

Comment: Yep, it works. Thanks, @gianluca aguzzi!